# How to make generic formal parameter aliased

Tags: generics, ada

I am trying to declare a formal parameter like so:

```
generic
   S : aliased String;
package My_Package is
   Str : access constant String := S'Access;
end;
```

But this code does not compile. Why can't I make S aliased?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ARM 12.4 (7)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-12-4.html#p7) says

> For a generic formal object of mode in, the actual shall be an expression. For a generic formal object of mode in out, the actual shall be a name that denotes a variable for which renaming is allowed (see 8.5.1).

and an expression can’t be aliased.

Even if you make `S` `in out`, you still can’t make it aliased.

You could say

```
generic
   S : String;
package My_Package is
   T : aliased String := S;
   Str : access constant String := T'Access;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

The simple answer is: because the Ada standard does not allow that. As for why it is not allowed, I do not know; I'm not aware of any discussion of the issue.

Why do you want to do that?

Your example code is of course incorrect in another way too: the initialization of Str should provide an access value, not a string value like S. But you cannot use S'Access since S is not aliased.

With GNAT, you can use S'Unrestricted_Access, even if the formal object is not aliased. If you do that, you should use the mode "in out" for the formal object; that will make it act like a renaming, more or less equivalent to pass-by-reference.

Comment: I need to be able to access the formal parameter from the outside after instantiating the package.

Comment: Perhaps you can make the generic formal parameter be an access to a String object?

Comment: @АндрейГриценко, if you use an `in out` formal parameter, you can still interact with the item in the outside. you don't need `aliased` or `access` for that. And if you need to ensure that a client of the instantiated generic can manipulate things, build that interface into the generic.